# Buscar dados de uma tabela com banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, table

Peço a ajuda de vocês em meu código. Estou criando um código php a qual pode fazer Reservas de certos carros, o básico que é reservar o carro para usuário x eu já consigo fazer. O problema, que na verdade vai aparecer apenas no futuro, é na hora de seleciona o Carro, enquanto tem poucos carros fica fácil achar o seu favorito porem com o decorrer do tempo a tabela vai aumentar e muito e vai ficar muito cansativo ficar procurando o seu carro preferido. Eu queria saber se é possível criar um `button` "Buscar Carro" onde o usuário colocaria o nome do carro no `input` e ao clicar no botão a tabela onde está todos os carros seja atualizada e apareça todos os carros com aquele Nome. Caso não tenha nenhum carro com aquele nome apareça um `alert` falando que não existe nenhum carro com essa nome.

Sou Novato em programação e por isso não sei se é possível fazer isso em `Php`, caso seja poderiam me ajudar ?

Esse é o código a qual estou criando

**Reserva.php**

```html
<body>
 <?php
 include_once "conexao.php";
 ?>

   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NOME">Nome do Carro: </label>
            <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Nome do Carro" name="NOME"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 24;">Buscar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   <br>
  
<table id="tab" border="" width="430px">
  <form method="post">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Carro</th>
  <th>Marca</th>
  <th>Modelo</th>
  <th>Cor</th>
  <th>Ano</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 </style>
<center>

  <?php
            include_once "conexao.php";
            $sql = "select c.id_adm, c.id_carro, c.Nome_carro, c.Marca, c.Modelo, c.Cor, c.Ano_carro, a.id_adm, a.login from carros as c join adm as a on
            a.id_adm = c.id_adm ";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            if($result){
            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tbody>
       <tr id="<?php echo $linha['id_carro']; ?>">
           <td data-target="id_carro"> <?php  echo $linha['id_carro'];?></td>
           <td data-target="Nome_carro"> <?php echo $linha['Nome_carro'];?></td>
           <td data-target="Marca"> <?php echo $linha['Marca'];?></td>
           <td data-target="Modelo"> <?php echo $linha['Modelo'];?></td>  
           <td data-target="Cor"> <?php echo $linha['Cor'];?></td>  
           <td data-target="Ano_carro"> <?php echo $linha['Ano_carro'];?></td>       
           
       </tr>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $('tbody tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($('#'+id+" td"),function(){
            var target = $(this).data('target');
            $("input[name='"+target+"']").val($(this).html());
        });
    });
</script>
</tbody>
<?php
          }
      
          }
          mysql_close($con);
?>
</form>
</table>




  <p><h1>Marque um Horario</h1></p>

 <form method="post" action="evento.php?reserva=true">
  <div class="form-group your-id">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="id_carro" style="display: none">
  </div>
   
       <table>
 <tr>
  <td> Nome Carro:</td>
  <td><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="Nome_carro" disabled required></td>
</tr>
 
  
    
 <tr>
  <td align="right">Marca:</td>
  <td><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="Marca" disabled required></td>
</tr>
 
    
    
        
 <tr>
  <td align="right">Cor:</td>
  <td> <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="Cor" disabled required></td>
</tr>



   
 <tr>
  <td align="right">Ano:</td>
  <td> <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="Ano_carro" disabled required></td>
</tr>   
       

   </table>
  <table>
   <tr>
  <td><strong> Data:</strong></td>
  <td><input type="date" name="date" required><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><strong>Horario:</strong></td>
   <td><select name="horario" required>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   </select></td></tr>

   <tr><td><strong>Consessionaria:</strong></td>
   <td><select name="consessionariaa" required>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="Pontes Vieira">Pontes Vieira</option>
    <option value="Antonio Bezerra">Antonio Bezerra</option>
    <option value="João Feliciano">João Feliciano</option>
    <option value="Cezar Sales">Cezar Sales</option>
    <option value="Pedro Algusto Junior">Pedro Algusto Junior</option>
        <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
   </select></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Fazer Reserva"></td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
 </form>

</body>
```

**Conexao.php**

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>New Document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $login="root";
  $senha="";
  $banco="concessionaria";

  $con=mysql_connect($host,$login,$senha)or die("Erro ao conecta!".mysql_error());
  $sql="create database if not exists ".$banco;
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  mysql_select_db($banco,$con);
  $sql = "create table if not exists adm(
  id_adm int(8) auto_increment,
  login varchar(100) not null,
  senha varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(id_adm))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $sql = "create table if not exists usuario(
  id_usuario int(8) auto_increment,
  login varchar(100) not null,
  senha varchar(50) not null,
  cpf varchar(20) not null,
  rg varchar(20) not null,
  nome varchar(50) not null,
  telefone varchar(20) not null,
  cidade varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(id_usuario))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $sql="create table if not exists reserva(
    id_reserva int(8) auto_increment,
    data varchar(20) not null,
    horario varchar(50) not null,
    consessionaria varchar(50) not null,
    id_usuario int(8) not null,
    id_carro int(8) not null,
    foreign key(id_carro) references carros(id_carro),
    foreign key(id_usuario) references usuario(id_usuario),
    primary key(id_reserva))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $sql="create table if not exists carros(
    id_carro int(8) auto_increment,
    Nome_carro varchar(50) not null,
    Marca varchar(50) not null,
    Modelo varchar(50) not null,
    Cor varchar(50) not null,
    Ano_carro int(8) not null,
    id_adm int(8) not null,
    foreign key(id_adm) references adm(id_adm),
    primary key(id_carro))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom primeiramente vejo que você está usando ainda as funções mysql e é melhor você atualizar seu script todo para o mysqli ou para o pdo que é o que eu recomendo de uma pesquisada depois para saber o por que, pois as funções do mysql já nem existem mais no PHP ou seja foram retiradas, agora respondendo a sua pergunta SIM como você está usando mysql de uma olhada neste link [bem Aqui](http://rafaelcouto.com.br/sistema-de-busca-interna-com-php-mysql/) que você vai achar um sistema de busca feito em mysql como você quer